Как составить запрос UPDATE из массива?
Есть массив
['pole'  => 'str',
 'pole1' => 4,
 'pole2' => 15]

Необходимо получить строчку и массив следующего вида
`pole` = ?, `pole1` = ?, `pole2` = ?
['str', 4, 15]

Это для запроса update в pdo
$PDO->SQL("UPDATE `table` set `pole` = ?, `pole1` = ?, `pole2` = ?", ['str', 4, 15])

В целом не трудно, просто если я сделаю, код длиною в том получиться. Через цикл массив перебрать...
Возможно есть более простой способ,не знаю будет ли работать если для второй строчки просто вставить массив какой он есть. Возможно не будет, поскольку ключи не порядковые...
В изначальном массиве, ключ это поле, а значение это то что в данное поле необходимо записать...

Вы на правильном пути, так что делайте сами. Циклов бояться не надо. В PDO можно использовать именованные плейсхолдеры, и тогда массив можно будет передать как есть.  Только вместо ? надо писать в запрос  :$key

Вариант 1, foreach:
Создайте пустой массив $q_fields_arr = []
Добавьте обрамленное значение в конец массива $q_fields_arr[] = "$k = ?";
Соберите массив в строку, используя в качестве разделителя ", " implode(', ',$q_fields_arr)
$input = ['pole'  => 'str',
 'pole1' => 4,
 'pole2' => 15];
$q_fields_arr = [];
foreach($input as $k=>$v){
    $q_fields_arr[] = "`$k` = ?";
}
$q_fields = implode(', ',$q_fields_arr);
$q_vals = array_values($input);
print $q_fields.PHP_EOL;
print_r($q_vals);


Вариант 2, array_map:
Используйте array_keys чтобы получить ключи.
Затем, чтобы перебрать все ключи - array_map, в возвращаемом значении обрамляя нужным текстом ({key}=?)
Затем implode - чтобы сформировать из массива строку.
Функция array_values вернёт вам значения массива, без именованных ключей.
<?php

$input = ['pole'  => 'str',
 'pole1' => 4,
 'pole2' => 15];
 
$q_fields = implode(', ',array_map(function($k){
    return "`$k` = ?";
},array_keys($input)));

$q_vals = array_values($input);
print $q_fields.PHP_EOL;
print_r($q_vals);


Результат
`pole` = ?, `pole1` = ?, `pole2` = ?
Array
(
    [0] => str
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 15
)


Вариант 3: PDO Placeholders
В этом случае, нам не нужно убирать ключи из исходного массива.
<?php
// Enter your code here, enjoy!
$input = ['pole'  => 'str',
 'pole1' => 4,
 'pole2' => 15];
$q_fields_arr = [];
foreach($input as $k=>$v){
    $q_fields_arr[] = "`$k` = :$k";
}
$q_fields = implode(', ',$q_fields_arr);

print $q_fields.PHP_EOL;
print_r($input);

Результат:
`pole` = :pole, `pole1` = :pole1, `pole2` = :pole2
Array
(
    [pole] => str
    [pole1] => 4
    [pole2] => 15
)


По просьбам телезрителей:
Тут implode вынесена в цикл.
Если бы у нас был массив без ключей, мы бы могли делать проверку $k!=0
В данном случае, мы обращаемся к внутреннему указателю массива next(), чтобы проверить, существует ли следующий элемент, чтобы избежать лишнего добавления разделителя ", "
Так же используется тернарный оператор if, исключельно для того, чтобы показать его существование )
<?php
// Enter your code here, enjoy!
$input = ['pole'  => 'str',
 'pole1' => 4,
 'pole2' => 15];
$q_fields='';
$q_vals = [];
foreach($input as $k=>$v){
    $q_fields.= "`$k` = ?".(next($input)?', ':'');
    $q_val[]=$v;
}

print $q_fields.PHP_EOL;
print_r($q_val);


"Как на пустом месте из O(n) сделать O(n*5) и заморочить новичку голову". Я понимаю, что хочется выглядеть попонтовее. Но надо всё-таки учитывать, что вы не девочке код показываете. И не на олимпиаде выделываетесь. А  помогаете живому человеку, который и просто цикл-то написать не может. И лучшей помощью было бы показать ему этот цикл, а не давать сильно неоптимальный код, который он гарантированно не поймёт.

@Ипатьев Хорошо, добавьте свой ответ. В данном примере, я хотел показать, что существуют полезные функции для работы с массивами.

@Ипатьев Дополнил ответ.

Спасибо за дополнение! Функции для массивов-то есть, но показать, что они не всегда к месту, тоже полезно :) Я бы вот даже для наглядности получение $q_fields и $q_vals сделал внутри того же цикла, перебирая исходный массив ровно один раз, а не три, как сейчас. Но это уже совсем придирки.

@Ипатьев пожалуйcта XD
